# multiple case and count

Tags: sql

```
select 

 Count(case 
        when col.1='aa' and  col.2 = 'True' THEN ???
        when col.1='bb' and col.2 = 'True' THEN ???
             
        else 0
        end) 
             
from table
```

Note - col.2 should always be 'True'

I want the select clause to return count of all records which has
'aa' in col.1 as "total no. of aa"  ,
'bb' in col.2 as 'total no. of bb"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `group by` is the simplest method:

```
select col1, count(*)
from t
where col2 = 'True'
group by col1;
```

This puts the results in different rows.  If you want different columns, then:

```
select sum(case when col1 = 'aa' then 1 else 0 end) as aa,
       sum(case when col1 = 'bb' then 1 else 0 end) as bb
from t
where col2 = 'True';
```

I see no reason to include the comparison to `'True'` in the `case` expression.

Answer (score 1):

do you want this

```
select col1,count(*) from (
select 
 case 
    when col.1='aa' and  col.2 = 'True' THEN ???
    when col.1='bb' and col.2 = 'True' THEN ???
    
    else 0
    end col1
    from table)set
 group by col1
```